# C++ Math Weird After 65536

Tags: c++, math, integer

This is my first question asked so I am not sure exactly what to say. Basically, I wrote a program to find the diagonal of a rectangular prism with the inputs for length, width, and height being whole numbers ranging from 1 - 100,000. (The output of this function would only be stated in the console if it was a whole number.) Everything seems to work until it got to the number 65536, after which, the next output was 0.
I am still new to programming, and if I missed anything, feel free to ask, thank you all in advance!

```c++
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include <cmath>

int l = 1;
int w = 1;
int h = 1;

double temp1;
double temp2;
double Hypo1;
double temp3;
double Hypo2;
double temp4;

int main(){

while(h < 100000){

//Math to find diagonal of rectangular prism.
temp1 = l * l;
temp2 = w * w;
Hypo1 = temp1 + temp2;

temp3 = h * h;
temp4 = Hypo1 + temp3;
Hypo2 = sqrt(temp4);

//Output if answer is a whole number.
if(abs(floor(Hypo2)) == Hypo2){
std::cout << "<Length = "; std::cout << l;
std::cout << " | Width = "; std::cout << w;
std::cout << " | Height = "; std::cout << h;
std::cout << ">";
std::cout << "     Total:"; std::cout << Hypo2 << std::endl;
}

//Add one to each input.
if(l == w && l == h){
l++;
}
else if(w < l && w == h){
w++;
}
else if(h < l && h < w){
h++;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code (for example like the samples in your C++ text book).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the wonders of **Overflow**.

So, here's what's happening:

You're using `int`, which stores values in a 4 byte (32 bit) variable. When you multiply two numbers stored in X bits you may need to store the result in 2*X bits.

In this case, 65536 is, in binary, **0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000** (in hex, **0x 0001 0000**). When you multiply 65536 by itself, the result will be **1 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000** (in hex, **0x 1 0000 0000**). Now, the problem is that this value needs **33** bits to be correctly stored. As it only has **32**, it stored the **32 least significant bits** and **discards the most significant bit**. As such, the stored value will be 0. This is also what happens with greater values.

To correct this, replace `int` with `long long` or, even better, `unsigned long long`.

As a personal advice, get used to `uint32_t` and other standard types. They will come in handy. To use these, `#include <cstdint>`. In this case, you should use `uint64_t` to store unsigned integers in a 64-bit variable

Comment: `long` may very well have the same length as `int` depending on the platform. It should be `long long`.

Comment: `long` isn't required to be 64-bit

Comment: My bad, I'm used to only use "uint64_t" when I want a 64-bit integer.

Comment: ...and you should mention that `uint32_t` requires `#include <cstdint>` and that he should then use `uint64_t`.

Comment: Just nitpicking, `uint32_t` et al. are *optional* typedefs. `uint_least32_t` would be "more correct" (on systems that have some strange `CHAR_BITS != 8`). ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You declared `h` as an `int`, so the result of `h*h` will also be an int. The conversion to double happens after the calculation is already done.

If you take a look at `INT_MAX` it's probably `2,147,483,647` on your platform.

So if you look at `65536 * 65536` it's `4,294,967,296`, well outside of the value range.

If you convert one of the factors into a double value first, you might have some more luck `temp3 = double(h) * h`

Comment: ..or just replace `int l = 1;` etc. with `double l = 1;` etc.